# How to segment given image by simple method in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have one image. I want to segment it by simple approach. Could you suggest to me the best method to segment it by matlab? Please see  my given image file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ptym1zik6j35fq4/imagetest.mat)
and segmented image file below [image: here] (Red color is boundary of segmented image)

Comment: Better to show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following piece of code could serve as a starting point.

```
I = load('imagetest.mat');
I = I.imagetest;
I = I./max(I(:));
se = strel('disk', 3);
Io = imopen(I, se);
Ie = imerode(I, se);
Iobr = imreconstruct(Ie, I);
Iobrd = imdilate(Iobr, se);
Iobrcbr = imreconstruct(imcomplement(Iobrd), imcomplement(Iobr));
Iobrcbr = imcomplement(Iobrcbr);
bw = im2bw(Iobrcbr, graythresh(Iobrcbr));
figure
imshow(bw, 'InitialMagnification', 'fit')
title('Binary image')
```

The output is

[image]

You can use the `watershed` command to get the watershed ridge lines that separate the black and white segments. Some of the parameters with which one could experiment are the morphological structuring element (`strel` command), the level returned by `graythresh`, and the succession and type of morphological operations.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the threshold, the simplest way is :

```
BW = im2bw(I, level)
```

where `I` is the grayscale image, and `level` is the threshold value. Another less hard way to threshold is the [local adaptive threshold](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8647-local-adaptive-thresholding). It will base the threshold decision on the mean intensity of a local window. Again, nothing fancy here, simplest possible segmentation.

Answer (score 2):

There is no general definition of segments. Sometimes people want to segment objects or foreground from background or parts of objects or text. You have to define what kind of segmentation you want. For text you can use [adaptive threshold](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=adaptivet#cv.AdaptiveThreshold), for grey level shape images you can use [connected components](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=floodfill#cv.FloodFill), for objects you can use blur cue if it is available, for color scenes GMM - Gaussian mixture models - can be appropriate, see [grab cut](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=grabcut#cv2.grabCut).

Comment: I am using matlab to do it. For this problem, I am using one advance technique to segment one part of gray image. But the technique  fails to segment in above part (I showed it in file). The method will build image into an energy function and try to optimal it. To improve it, I find some techniques that construct image as energy function. Grab cut is one of them. But it is very complex time and need to define seed point. Threshold needs to know the threshold value. In my case, I want to build automatically. I think clustering is best. Do you think that.

Comment: in K-means clustering you have to specify the number of clusters. There are library functions for this in openCV and in Matlab. (http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/clustering.html?highlight=kmean#cv.KMeans2). If you also want to model the extent of each cluster independently use a Guassian mixture model. The problem is that your data don’t look like either. What do your data represent?

Comment: My data is special data in medical image. I think I will use multiple threshold to do it. It is more simple than other method. And I will find how to determine its threshold. In my above case. I will set threshold are 250 and 300

Comment: Use k-means in intensity or color space instead of image space. In intensity space which is one dimensional plot all point intensities, find two clusters and use their means as thresholds.